Apache Kafka with kraft cluster connection not established
I have set up a 3-node Kafka KRaft cluster with each node acting as both a broker and a controller. However, when I check the metadata quorum status, each node seems to act as a separate leader instead of forming a single consistent cluster. Below are the details of my setup and configuration:
server.properties 1
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=0
controller.quorum.voters=0@10.0.0.4:19092,1@10.0.0.5:19093,2@10.0.0.6:19094
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.6:9092,CONTROLLER://10.0.0.6:19092
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.4:9092,CONTROLLER://10.0.0.4:19092
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

server.properties 2
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=0@10.0.0.4:19092,1@10.0.0.5:19093,2@10.0.0.6:19094
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.6:9092,CONTROLLER://10.0.0.6:19093
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.5:9092,CONTROLLER://10.0.0.5:19093
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

server.properties 3
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=2
controller.quorum.voters=0@10.0.0.4:19092,1@10.0.0.5:19093,2@10.0.0.6:19094
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.6:9092,CONTROLLER://10.0.0.6:19094
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.6:9092,CONTROLLER://10.0.0.6:19094
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

Is any configuration am missed out?
